# Bootstrap form won't center

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an opt in form on this site that I can't seem to get centered.

I've created a class called .center and wrapped it around the form but it isn't working.

```
.center {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 100%
}
```

I imagine that one of Bootstraps many classes is overriding it but I can't seem to find it. You can view the problem on the form at the BOTTOM of the page [here](http://www.theplaybook.co).

Comment: Add text-align: center; .

Answer (score 3):

Just add `text-align: center;` to your center class.

The problem you have is, that the div has 100% width, so **IT IS** centered, but the inner content is floating left.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Since the div is using 100% of it's outer container it is centered. This fixed it. Thanks Bernhard!